# Tracking Individual Processes in Windows Server 2008, Is It Possible?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, memory-usage, memory-leak, monitoring

I'm hoping we can get a solution together on this.  I'm looking to try and narrow down what's happening on a windows server 2008 box that's causing us to have to reboot every 2 weeks.  Resource monitor would show that there's some sort of memory leak going on but we are having problems determining what application is causing the problem.

Does anyone know of a good solution for logging memory usage on a per-process level?  We're hoping to log the output over a section of like 2-4 weeks and see what happens.

Any help is appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools available to help you track down issues like this.

Start with the [performance monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) which is provided with your OS. You can set it up to take periodic snapshot of pretty much any metric you can think of, including individual memory usage per process. In your case, that's probably the best tool for identifying rogue processes.

Also [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), which you'll have to download, is a very good way if looking into all processes of your system. It will allow you explore your system state in a very detailed way.

Finally, you can use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), also a separate download, to watch a particular process activity in detail.

Comment: Got it.  Data Collector Set FTW I believe.  Thank you very much Stephane.

Answer (score 1):

WSRM does this, if you enable the process accounting.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx.

Comment: A better link for this approach might be [Audit process tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)